# How do i connect two meshes together without ruining the topology

Tags: modeling, topology

I am having a lot of trouble connecting the hands and head to the body. They always have more edges than the body meaning I can't connect them through quads.

Is there some technique to make them connect to the body while still using quads?

Comment: Yes, you can use loop reduction: http://topologyguides.com/post/163679954765/loop-reduction

Comment: thx very much this helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to reduce the edge loops' amount using *diamond quads*. They're very helpful for making the mesh less dense in certain parts. Also helps to create the proper edge flow defining the model's shape in some cases. In the example pictured below I reduced the 24 vertices loop to 12 vertices loop.
[image]

Diamond pattern- loop reduction from 3-1, 5-1 and 5-3 examples:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Another loops reduction method is pictured below.
[image]

Loops reduction from 4-2, 6-2 and 7-3:
[image]
[image]
[image]

***Note:*** The complete answer to your problem is in the link @LukeD provided in his comment, but since I've done this topology presentation for my friend some time ago I decided not to waste my efforts and share it with you. Hope it'll be helpful :).

Comment: it will take a while to get used to but this helped thanks

Comment: As usual great answer to a not so great question. Very well illustrated

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos I'm glad you like it friend! BTW Since I am really crazy about perfect topology I have to thank you for showing me the **topologyguides.com** (I remember you posted a link to the site in one of your answers/comments a long time ago). It's super helpful- a real decalogue for every pro modeller wanna be.

Comment: Indeed, found it by accident and is now my default go-to guide for answers here.