# How can I improve the topology in this character model?

Tags: retopology

I have finished sculpting this person. Now i've started making retopology. Could you check it and tell me, if I am on a right/wrong way.

[image]

In the future, I am planning to animate this person. So, as you see, some quads are smaller( eyes, cheeks, eyebrows), excuse me, all quads are small(is that wrong?).

And, some questions:

1. Do I need to avoid triangles every time, or it depends on mesh(muscles, smooth transitions)?
2. Can I continue body retopo, making large quads? Like here
   [image]
3. If you have some rare tips of retopo, please, share with me.

Thanks.

EDIT 1.

Made new topology, before - 3k vertices, after - 666

[image]

EDIT 2.
Before 666 vertices, after - 459

[image]

Comment: I would say stay low-poly as much as possible, but of course on some parts you won't be able because you need to model some details. Your topology can be simplify in my opinion, also try to keep a nice topology flow, for example see here how it circulates around the mouth: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/96/15/ac/9615ac0a46f7730b5b62a2e78bc3d24b.jpg

Comment: The edge flow is not recommended for animation.  Image search "face retopo" and examine the edge flow you see (loops around eyes, mouth

Comment: Thanks, i see that. One question: Reading some tips, i got that quads must copy muscles's shape, is that mean we are gonna lose a nice topology flow, or i am able to do that, or it could be simplified anyway? For example, muscles around neck, quads are not following the shape, as I see. Thanks

Comment: don't forget that you can use normal map, i.e. create a high poly character, sculpt, and save all the small details on a normal map so that you can fake 3D details on the low-poly version

Comment: It's better, but I still think you can use much less faces. Look at the cheeks, they're just a smooth almost flat surface, you don't need all those polygons there. Look at the references I posted on my answer.

Comment: The flow of the loops is much better already, but still not quite right. You didn't make loops going all the way around the mouth, you made U shapes that go below the mouth and go back straight up. And there's no loop that goes both around the mouth and the nose. This is important if you intend to animate the face.

Comment: [About edit 2]: There's still some room for improvement but it's definetely MUCH better than the first one. If I were the person that is going to rig the model, I would much rather rig this new version than the original one. Congratulations on the improvement!

Comment: thans!! I'm gonna improve that, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your new topology is too dense (far too many faces). The character(Goku?)'s face doesn't have too much detail (it's mostly smooth), so you can economize a lot more on the number of polygons.
Too many polygons make it harder to rig and creates a bigger computational load for working with the model and rendering.

Another issue is that you are modeling the eyes weld shut. Do you intend to just add a texture with the eye painted on? Did you think about how you will animate eye direction, blinking and things like that? I would recommend creating the eyeballs as separate objects and 'carving' eye sockets and modeling the eyelids  on the character's mesh.

Other than that my general tip is to try create edge loops that flow around the features of the face, like these exemples:

[image]

[image]

The exemples also show how much detail you can get without adding too many faces to your topology (consider that you will add a subdivision modifier later).

My last suggestion is to sculpt the character with a neutral, relaxed facial expression so you can create a facial rig to create any expression in the character when animating. Your character seems to be frowning.

To answer your questions:

1. You don't need to avoid triangles all the time at all costs. Just avoid them in general, but if it's inevitable and if it's in a part of the mesh that is not very likely to be evident it's not a huge problem. It's more important to avoid Ngons (faces with more than 4  sides) than triangles.
2. Wherever you can economize in the number of faces, do it. There are a few techniques to transition to a smaller number of loops. This is commonly needed in places like the wrist - the arm is a 'big' shape that requires lower density than the hand, which has to split into fingers and that requires more loops. [See this answer for more info on that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92574/102096).